# Enable git cloned nextcloud application

Tags: php, nextcloud

Can't enable a nextcloud application installed over `git clone`.
When I click enable button everything ok, the application moves to enabled, but after a page reloads it disabled again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was I forgot to install dependencies `composer install` so nextcloud can't require autoload file and disable application.

https://github.com/nextcloud/server/blob/106ea9fdaa9ff06c1d49cb0716a454946e0804e6/lib/private/legacy/app.php#L155